# DateTime.ToOADate - Time only

Tags: c#

I have a "DateTime" var with the current date (DateTime.Now).
I can convert this to a OADate-Format (41392,524432) as example.
But how I can convert this, that I'm **just** getting the time without the date?
For example 1 minute and 4 seconds (01:04) are 0,04444444 in this format.

Comment: Can't you do myDateTime.Date first and then convert?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it - could you explain it please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since [MSDN states that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx):

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899

you presumably want to use that as your base date:

```
DateTime oaBaseDate = new DateTime(1899,12,30);
double result = oaBaseDate.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).ToOADate();
```

or if you don't like magic numbers (magic dates), the equivalent:

```
DateTime oaBaseDate = DateTime.FromOADate(0);
double result = oaBaseDate.Add(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).ToOADate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try subtracting the current date.

```
double oaDate = DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
double result = oaDate - (int)(oaDate);
```

Or

```
double result = oaDate - Math.Floor(oaDate);
```

Comment: In case where date is prior to 1900, it should be Math.Truncate or Math.Ceiling when negative number. Math.Truncate is better since it works correctly here with both positive and negative numbers.