# Read date column from Excel

Tags: c#

I am reading a date column from an Excel file

```
var dt = new DataTable();
string query = string.Format("SELECT  * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);

con1.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con1);
adapter.Fill(dt);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
{
    con.Open();

    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j ++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0][j].ToString());

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Budget Geant Preload]([CA TTC], [VAL MRG TTC], [CA HT], [VAL MRG HT], [Rayon], [Date], [Code Site], [Rayon Correspondance], TVA) VALUES(NULL, NULL, @ca, NULL, @rayon, @date, '2000', @rayon, null )", con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt.Rows[0][j]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ca", dt.Rows[i][j]);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rayon", dt.Rows[i][0]);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

An example of data

[image]

I need to get `01/01/2015` but it returns `42217`. How to resolve it?

Comment: Do you have an example of the data in your excel file?

Comment: What is `dt.Rows[0][j]` exactly? How do you think we can possible know what value that your dt returns? Just debug your code.

Comment: then you might be using wrong index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datetime.fromOAdate() should do the work.

Update:

I just want to expand a bit on the answer.

In Excel, a date is stored as a floating point number which are the number of dates since the 1/1/1900. It could seem arbitrary, but it makes adding and subtracting time to (almost) just simple add and substract. Actually, in .net the date time struct is internally the same, just using ticks indestead.

Answer (score 3):

Check for [OAdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262007/datetime-tooadate-time-only)

```
var time = DateTime.FromOADate(42217);
```

Another reference about [Interop Dates](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fromoadate)